# Find item in array and push to other array

Tags: javascript

I have a bit of a puzzle. I have array1 of all awards

```
array1 = [
  {
    "finished": 1,
    "awardName": "The beginning",
    "description": "Complete one excersise",
    "difficulty": "easy",
    "awarded": false
  },
  {
    "finished": 5,
    "awardName": "Five of a kind",
    "description": "Complete five excersises",
    "difficulty": "medium",
    "awarded": false
  }, ... ]`
```

and array2 of awarded awards.

```
[
  {
    "award": "Five of a kind"
  },
  {
    "award": "The beginning"
  },
  {
    "award": "firstTimeLogin"
  }
]
```

What I want to do is to compare `awardNames` in both arrays and if there is award with the same name, change that objects `awarded` to `true`. It should look like this, `this.array1[indexOfSecondArrayContainingThatAwardname].awarded = true`. I hope this is possible, because I am not yet that skilles in javascript. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used with forEach and map.

```js
let array1 = [{
    "finished": 1,
    "awardName": "The beginning",
    "description": "Complete one excersise",
    "difficulty": "easy",
    "awarded": false
  },
  {
    "finished": 5,
    "awardName": "Five of a kind",
    "description": "Complete five excersises",
    "difficulty": "medium",
    "awarded": false
  }
]

const array2 = [{
    "award": "Five of a kind"
  },
  {
    "award": "The beginning"
  },
  {
    "award": "firstTimeLogin"
  }
]

array2.forEach(award2=>{
  array1 = array1.map(award1=>{
    if(award2.award === award1.awardName){
      award1.awarded = true;
    }
    return award1;
  })
});

console.log(array1);
```

Comment: Thanks man. It works. I guess all other answers work, so thanks everybody who answered. But I tried your first :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```js
const array1 = [{
    "finished": 1,
    "awardName": "The beginning",
    "description": "Complete one excersise",
    "difficulty": "easy",
    "awarded": false
  },
  {
    "finished": 5,
    "awardName": "Five of a kind",
    "description": "Complete five excersises",
    "difficulty": "medium",
    "awarded": false
  }
];

const array2 = [{
    "award": "Five of a kind"
  },
  {
    "award": "The beginning"
  },
  {
    "award": "firstTimeLogin"
  }
];

for (const { award } of array2) {
  const idx = array1.findIndex(i => i.awardName === award);
  if (idx !== -1) 
    array1[idx].awarded = true;
}

console.log(array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map and filter to chain throw the arrays and return your desired result

```js
var array1 = [
  {
    "finished": 1,
    "awardName": "The beginning",
    "description": "Complete one excersise",
    "difficulty": "easy",
    "awarded": false
  },
  {
    "finished": 5,
    "awardName": "Five of a kind",
    "description": "Complete five excersises",
    "difficulty": "medium",
    "awarded": false
  }
]
  

var array2 = [
  {
    "award": "Five of a kind"
  },
  {
    "award": "The beginning"
  },
  {
    "award": "firstTimeLogin"
  }
]

array1.map(ele =>{
  if (array2.filter(ele2 => ele.awardName === ele2.award).length > 0) ele.awarded = true;           
});

console.log(array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table and set with `array2` and check with array1``.

```js
var array1 = [{ finished: 1, awardName: "The beginning", description: "Complete one excersise", difficulty: "easy", awarded: false }, { finished: 5, awardName: "Five of a kind", description: "Complete five excersises", difficulty: "medium", awarded: false }],
    array2 = [{ award: "Five of a kind" }, { award: "The beginning" }, { award: "firstTimeLogin" }],
    map = Object.create(null);
  
array2.forEach(({ award }) => map[award] = true);

array1.forEach(o => map[o.awardName] && (o.awarded = true));

console.log(array1);
```